# Angular.js routing: how do I set a controller for the outer template?

Tags: angularjs, routes

This is probably simple but I can't get an answer in Angular docs. Consider the example about routing in the [Angular Routing docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). Here is the main html template.

```
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Every view has its own controller, as per:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

Everything fine so far, but:
QUESTION: how can I set up a controller for the main template?

Say, for example, that I want to have something like:

```
 <html>
 <body>
  <a ng-click="someFunction()">Function</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

How and where do I define `someFunction()`?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-controller as attribute in your html element, in this case body.

```
<html>
     <body ng-controller= "myController">
      <a ng-click="someFunction()">Function</a>
      <div ng-view></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Write your function in myController

```
app.controller("myController",function($scope){

       $scope.someFunction=function(){
          //your code
       }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ngController` directive:

```
<html>
 <body ng-controller="mainController">
  <a ng-click="someFunction()">Function</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

so for particular partial if you want a controller without mentioning in app.js  in that case you can use ng-controller.